# Initial slow query using spatial key and bounding box

Tags: mysql

This is my first question to SO so please be kind if I've left anything out.

This example query is a search of cars within a 30 mile range of Dallas, Texas. I'm using a bounding box to limit the rows to search.

The problem:

Prior to the query being cached, it takes about 20 seconds to retrieve 23,600 results. It looks like there are only
411 rows to search inside the bounding box. Shouldn't this be really fast?

Any ideas on why it is so slow? Any Suggestions on how to improve this? Am I doing something wrong?

The query:

```
SELECT Make, Model 
    FROM cars 
        WHERE MBRCONTAINS( GEOMFROMTEXT( 'Polygon(( 32.4800138808 -97.1620371512, 33.0933687128 -97.1620371512, 33.0933687128 -96.4324293136, 
        32.4800138808 -96.4324293136, 32.4800138808 -97.1620371512 ))' ) ,g )
```

Explain output:

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----
|  1 | SIMPLE      | carscom | range | g             | g    | 34      | NULL |  411 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------
```

There are about 1.2 million rows in this table.

Here is the table structure with the relevant columns and indexes. The actual tables has more columns and a few more indexes.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cars` (
  `Latitude` float(10,7) NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` float(10,7) NOT NULL,
  `Make` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Model` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `g` geometry NOT NULL,

  KEY `LatLon` (`Latitude`,`Longitude`),
  SPATIAL KEY `g` (`g`)

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

There is a spatial key on column `g`.

Here's the SQL to populate the `g` column and put a spatial index on it.

```
UPDATE `cars` SET `g` = GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',`Latitude`,' ',`Longitude`,')'));

ALTER TABLE `cars` ADD SPATIAL KEY `g` (`g`);
```

I don't understand why searching only 411 rows takes so long initially. Is there something wrong with the spatial column and key?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: MySQL server is 5.1.70, Server has 16GB of memory.
I also edited the my.cnf file to include skip-host-cache & skip-name-resolve and restarted MySQL server.

UPDATE 2, profile info:

```
Starting    7 µs
Checking Query Cache For Query  42 µs
Checking Permissions    2 µs
Opening Tables  8 µs
System Lock     2 µs
Table Lock  5 µs
Init    15 µs
Optimizing  5 µs
Statistics  39 µs
Preparing   13 µs
Executing   2 µs
Sending Data    163 µs
End     3 µs
Query End   1 µs
Freeing Items   15 µs
Logging Slow Query  1 µs
Cleaning Up     2 µs
```

Comment: What is long?? Can you also run an profile on that query? i think your query is I/O bounded because of the Using where...

Comment: assuming  55ms random disk acces time.. and your query is not using an covering index should have been "using index" in Extra column of your explain the time formula is something this ((411 * 2) * 0.0055) ~ 4,5 seconds... because an index lookup is needed and random data from the data file is needed that why the * 2

Comment: Thanks Raymond, I updated my question with profile info. I thought a covering index too but I did try that and it seems mixing a spatial index with regular indexes doesn't work. I didn't see "using index" like I thought.

Comment: Can post an PROFILE like this?    SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY query_id  it looks like the MyISAM engine is providing an wrong estimate off rows 411 is way off 23600 rows

Comment: Actually the 411 rows would be correct because that is what the bounding box does. It eliminates all the lat/lons it doesn't need to search.

Comment: When I dropped and added back the spatial index `g`, the initial query went from 20 seconds down to a couple seconds. I don't understand why but that seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: most likely index fragmentation this is known to slow down range scans or your index stats are up to date now..

Comment: Apparently doing updates on the table can corrupt the spatial index which is what happened to me. Doing Repair/Optimize/Analyze table didn't help in my case, just dropping and adding back the spatial index fixed it. I have 3 tables with a spatial index and I was doing some updates on them today and the same super slow queries happened. Dropped the spatial indexes, re-adding them and then doing an Analyze table sped up the query. Hope this helps other people, drove me crazy!